# Predefining select2 data from Angular's binding

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

I have a select2 multivalue form input which gets the data from the backend.

It works when I want to populate it with data but, I want to predefine some values here AND have the ability to add/remove more tags as I please.

My $scope.post is as follows:

```
{
  "post": {
  "title": "test for tags",
  "description": "test for tags",
  "category": "Hospital",
  "dateCreated": "2017-12-12T04:44:24.629Z",
  "tags": [
    "shayan",
    "bruce-lee",
    "imran-khan-(official)"
    ],
  }
}
```

I want the tagsSearch field (below in HTML) to be set to: "shayan", "bruce-lee" and "imran-khan-(official)". As you can see, this is bound to Angular's $scope.post

My HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="tagsSearch" class="form-control" ng-model="post.tags" id="tags" style="width: 100%"></select>
</div>
```

My select2 implementation (but it is irrelevant for now as the searching is working).

```
$(".tagsSearch").select2({
    placeholder: 'Search for tags',
    delay: 250,
    tags: true,
    multiple: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    minimumResultsForSearch: 1,
    ajax: {
        url: function (params) {
            return '/api/searchTags';
        },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                text: params.term 
            };
        },
        processResults: function(data){
            return{
                results: $.map(data, function(obj){
                return {
                    id: obj.name, text: obj.name
                };
              })
            };
        }}
  })
);
```

My searchTags response is as follows (for example):

```
[
    {
    "_id": "5a1909180fe59b0580302743",
    "name": "bruce-lee",
    }
]
```

I think I am missing something very obvious here but am not being able to crack it.

Thanks in advance for helping out.

PS: I have looked at previous posts of a similar issue. None of it were a) similar to my implementation or b) working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A jQuery plugin with AngularJS?

The core problem with your code is that you're mixing a jQuery plugin with AngularJS. Select2 is already designed to work with AngularJS in [this component](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select). You should migrate to using it as soon as possible. But, this is not the only reason why your code doesn't work.

#### Why your code is not working?

Well, you are directly assigning the tags array to `ng-model`. To get Select2 plugin working, you better need to provide `options` in the `select` tags, which is done by [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive. Also, because you're supporting multiple selections, AngularJS needs to know that the select box support multiple selections. So, setting `multiple` attribute in select box is to be done. Finally, `ngOptions` directive works in collaboration with [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to bind the selected values to a scope variable.

Here is how your `select` box is tranformed after the above modifications:

```
<select class="tagsSearch" class="form-control" id="tags" ng-options="tag for tag in post.post.tags" ng-model="post.post.tags" style="width: 100%" multiple></select>
```

Putting all these together (and changing the code a bit), you can find [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mt8fjy7n/1/) working as per your requirements.

#### The result

You wanted the select2 box to show all the selected tags. This code selects all the tags which are defined by `$scope.selectedTags` variable.

#### Further work

You can use AJAX to set this variable (`$scope.selectedTags`) as per your need. Just remember to read the documentation of [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), so that you don't fall into common bugs.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius!. I am working on a project (full stack) and do easily get lost in scenarios like these. Thanks a lot for your help. (Can give the bounty in 1 hour it says)